# c++ DMS with subtitle support on LG smart tv with platinium library

Tags: c++, subtitle, dlna, smart-tv

I'm trying to implement a simple DMS that can provide subtitle information to the DMR -LG SmartTV - using platinium library.

I already succeeded to render video on the DMR and i already found where the DMR receive the information of the subtitle associated to the video file.

Sample request from the DMR:

```
    POST /upnp/services/ContentDirectory/control HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.1.3:54444
CONTENT-LENGTH: 735
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1#Browse"
USER-AGENT: Linux/2.6.39.4.ps-110224-lg1152 UPnP/1.0 DLNADOC/1.50 INTEL_NMPR/2.0 LGE_DLNA_SDK/1.6.0

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <s:Body>
    <u:Browse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1">
      <ObjectID>ea06</ObjectID>
      <BrowseFlag>BrowseDirectChildren</BrowseFlag>
      <Filter>@id,@parentID,@restricted,@childCount,dc:title,dc:creator,upnp:artist,upnp:class,dc:date,upnp:album,upnp:genre,res,res@size,res@duration,res@protection,res@bitrate,res@resolution,res@protocolInfo,res@nrAudioChannels,res@sampleFrequency,upnp:albumArtURI,upnp:albumArtURI@dlna:profileID, res@dlna:cleartextSize</Filter>
      <StartingIndex>0</StartingIndex>
      <RequestedCount>24</RequestedCount>
      <SortCriteria></SortCriteria>
    </u:Browse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

now the response from a valid DMS that support subtitle display is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
SERVER: WINDOWS/5.1 UPnP/1.0 DLNADOC/1.50 Nero-MediaHome/4.5.20.145
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset=utf-8
EXT:
DATE: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 22:12:35 GMT
TRANSFER-ENCODING: chunked
CONNECTION: Keep-Alive
...
          <item id="ea13" parentID="ea06" restricted="1">
            <dc:date>2012-10-25</dc:date>
            <dc:title>video.avi</dc:title>
            <upnp:album>Filmes</upnp:album>
            <upnp:class>object.item.videoItem.movie</upnp:class>
            <res 
              bitrate="257570" duration="1:37:32" nrAudioChannels="6" 
              protocolInfo="http-get:*:video/avi:DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000" 
              resolution="720x304" sampleFrequency="48000" size="1507196928">http://192.168.1.3:54444/server/80402875-CA74-4CCE-B7E0-D81CEF1913A2/D5E59F25/ea13?unknown-id</res>
            <res protocolInfo="http-get:*:text/srt:*">http://192.168.1.3:54444/server/80402875-CA74-4CCE-B7E0-D81CEF1913A2/3A2C7131/ea13?sub=video.srt</res>
          </item>
```

Now i'm trying to implement the same in my custom DMS, can anyone point me in the right direction or show any sample that implements subtitle info stored in res element as: srt_URL (content-type of response is text/srt)

Thanks

Comment: Tell me what you already got with Platinum. Have you compiled a test DMS from Source/Tests/FileMediaServer? Or perhaps even crafted your own implementation based off Source/Devices/MediaServer/PltFileMediaServer?

Comment: Yes, i'm extending the FileMediaServerTest, i create a new project (win32 service) and use the code in the project 'FileMediaServerTest' from platinium test projects

Comment: And that works for you, so that DMR can play files served by Platinum and it's only about adding <res> for subtitles?

Comment: yap, it works, the problem is that subtitles aren't display and images do not show preview (video also, but this is for the second version :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a SRT resource tag to UPnP item in Platinum, you should do at least the following. I don't claim the list being functional, complete or tested. It's just my best guess at what needs to be changed. If it doesn't immediately work as expected, i may not be able to help you more specifically. *It's a navigation hint, not a driving assistance*.

- put your SRT file in the same folder as the media file, named the same way in some sensible way which would be easy for you to distinguish afterwards.
- in **PltMimeType.cpp** add `"srt","text/srt"` to `PLT_HttpFileRequestHandler_DefaultFileTypeMap`. Platinum doesn't know SRT out of the box.
- **PltFileMediaServer.cpp** is kinda dumb, it by default shows up all files found in a directory. It's an example, after all. You need to filter out SRTs from the visible listing by implementing `PltFileMediaServer::ProcessFile` filter.
- still in **PltFileMediaServer.cpp** there is a method `PLT_FileMediaServerDelegate::BuildFromFilePath`. Here comes `filepath` which is the path of your media file (and ONLY that). Out of the filepath, you need to look in the folder whether there is a properly named subtitle file (with some `NPT_File` methods, look it up).
- if there is, you must add extra `PLT_MediaItemResource` to the `PLT_MediaObject* object`. There is already one `resource` instance, but that's used exclusively for the media resource itself. Don't reuse it. You need to add another one, and IMO you need to set only `resource.m_Uri` (with BuildResourceUri) and `resource.m_ProtocolInfo`.
- for `m_ProtocolInfo`, you need to call `PLT_ProtocolInfo::GetProtocolInfo` with parameter `false` so that the `protocolInfo` of your newly added `<res>` is not clobbered with DLNA profile id.

Comment: Many thanks all that you say it's correct and i successful display subtitles in my DMR with my software, now i only need to make this more pretty, showing images previews and video previews... do you know where i can find documentation to accomplish this (only dlna info) or some code samples too. Thanks again.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "image preview" or "video preview". You may want to implement transcoding of images and/or videos to smaller size, and present it as alternative resource to every item. But in terms of UPnP/DLNA it will be just an alternative resource, and it's fully up to DMR implementation whether it will display them. For example, UPnP does support specific `albumArtURI` for music (and DLNA has tons of specs for it), but my personal experience is that real-world DMRs prefer to display an image found as IDv3 tag in MP3 and ignore your precious UPnP data.

Comment: If you think you're able to explain clearly what you want, post a new question. Piggybacking on another question with irrelevant title is a bad practice because it complicates searching for knowledge.

Comment: it is not necessary, you already point me into the right direction. thanks again